# Logout from web page

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to logout from web page and Im getting this an error 
"This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Feb 28 21:33:53 GMT 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Expected CSRF token not found. Has your session expired?@

Eclipse generate this an error >>>

Hibernate: select statusupda0_.id as id1_0_, statusupda0_.added as added2_0_, statusupda0_.text as text3_0_ from status_update statusupda0_ order by statusupda0_.added desc limit ?
Hibernate: select siteuser0_.id as id1_1_, siteuser0_.email as email2_1_, siteuser0_.password as password3_1_ from user siteuser0_ where siteuser0_.email=?
Hibernate: select statusupda0_.id as id1_0_, statusupda0_.added as added2_0_, statusupda0_.text as text3_0_ from status_update statusupda0_ order by statusupda0_.added desc limit ?

And this is one of part from default.jsp page >>>

```
        <sec:authorize access="!isAuthenticated()">
                <li><a href="${contextRoot}/login">Login</a></li>
            </sec:authorize>

            <sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">

                <li><a href="javascript:$('#logoutForm').submit();">Logout</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"
                    data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded="false">Status <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="${contextRoot}/addstatus">Add Status</a></li>
                        <li><a href="${contextRoot}/viewstatus">View Status
                                Updates</a></li>

                    </ul></li>
            </sec:authorize>
```

Any tips?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Indeed Spring wasn't able to process the request properly. The message `This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback` tells you that Sprint tried to forward you to the /error handler to show the user an error page. The reason for that seems to be a missing CSRF token.

You're using Spring security? Place the CSRF token into your webpage. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-include-csrf-token for details

Comment: @AnsgarSchulte Thanks for the reply. You were right. I've added same CSRF token that has been used in login but I still have problem. Im getting this an error There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

Comment: Problem has been solved. Thanks again!